# After destroying DataMapper object in ruby v2.6.2, the Time field is returned in UTC

Tags: ruby, datetime, object, memory, datamapper

I have the following DataMapper class:

```
class Test
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :created_at, Time
end
```

In ruby 2.2 if I do the following:

```
tst = Test.first
puts tst.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
tst.destroy
puts tst.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

I get:

> 2019-06-17T15:11:46 <--- GMT+3
>
> 2019-06-17T15:11:46 <--- GMT+3

In ruby 2.6 I get:

> 2019-06-17T15:11:46 <--- GMT+3
>
> 2019-06-17T12:11:46 <--- UTC

So, after destroying the object, the created_at field is returning the date in UTC. Is this the right behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug that you should report to datamapper author.

Comment: DataMapper has been replaced by ROM a long time ago.